# Android Click Listeners for list with multiple buttons per row

Tags: android, listadapter

I'm using an ArrayAdapter to display my friends in a list. Each row, however, has two buttons that will update the friend's status via a POST request.

I defined the click listeners for the two buttons, as well as the runnable to handle the update request, in the adapter. An example:

```
mToggleAlert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                mToggleAlert = (ToggleButton)finalRowView.findViewById(R.id.toggleAlert);
                mToggleShow = (ToggleButton)finalRowView.findViewById(R.id.toggleShow);
                updateStatus(finalRowView.getId(), mToggleAlert.isChecked(), mToggleShow.isChecked());
            }
        });



    /**
     * Send the updated status to the server
     */
    private void updateStatus(int id, boolean alert, boolean show) {

        final int finalId = id;
        final boolean finalAlert = alert;
        final boolean finalShow = show;

        String.valueOf(mToggleAlert);

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                //Post the update to the server
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.postFriendStatusUrl);

                try {

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",Common.retrieveAppUser(mContext).getId()));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friend_id", String.valueOf(finalId)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alert_status", String.valueOf(finalAlert)));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("show_status", String.valueOf(finalShow)));

                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    // Execute HTTP Post Request
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream is = httpEntity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    bundle.putString("result", sb.toString());
                    msg.setData(bundle);

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                }




                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        };

        Thread mythread = new Thread(runnable);
        mythread.start();


    }
```

I don't think this is a good way to approach this, though, so I put the update service into it's own AsyncTask.

My question is: I would rather define the click listeners for the two buttons in the Activity that implements the ArrayAdapter, not in the adapter itself. How do I do this?

Comment: create your customadapter extending the baseadapter class, [see here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

Answer (score 0):

```
    mToggleAlert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            mToggleAlert = (ToggleButton)finalRowView.findViewById(R.id.toggleAlert);
            mToggleShow = (ToggleButton)finalRowView.findViewById(R.id.toggleShow);
            updateStatus(finalRowView.getId(), mToggleAlert.isChecked(), mToggleShow.isChecked());
        }
    });
```

Is it normal that you only set the listener to the mToggleAlert ans not on the mToggleShow ?

Anyway, you can put getters from your buttons in the ArrayAdapter

```
public ToogleButton getToggleAlert(){
    return mToggleAlert;
}
```

And then you will be able to set the listener from the main activity

You might just need to set "updateStatus" public to call it from your activity